# Can I set the UIFont height?

Tags: iphone, uifont

Can I set the UIFont height as well as the line spacing?
I googled this, it seems no way to set height for the IOS built-in font. One possible way is to use customized font. This seems too heavy since I just want to set line spacing and height.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you figure this out? UIFontDescriptor is incredibly complex and painful for such a simple attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get an `UIFont` instance from iOS for the given size, you can't alter size later.
because it define all of it's property as `readonly`.

you could access the height of character for Caps and Lower using the properties.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat xHeight
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CGFloat lineHeight
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat capHeight
```